# How to upload a csv file to AWS S3 using API gateway and lambda in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I have a requirement where in i have to pass a csv file from POST method and receive it from Lambda and push  it to S3.

Comment: And what do you expect as an answer? That someone will code it for you? (this is not a free code service) Or do you have a specific problem with it? There are plenty of examples if you search  a little. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you considered uploading directly from the browser to Amazon S3 instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are other posts on here which deal with dumping a file to an S3 bucket from an AWS Lambda function.  Usually with boto3. For example [Writing a file to S3 using Lambda in Python with AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163099/writing-a-file-to-s3-using-lambda-in-python-with-aws)