# Save image data from a iterator object to AWS S3 in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am calling an API that returns a iterator object containing image data. I'd like to iterate over them and upload to s3. I could either open them into `.png` or `.jpeg` before or after dumping / uploading them to s3.

```
import boto3

# Download / open photo
img_obj = gmaps.places_photo(ph, max_width = 500, max_height = 400)
            
print(img_obj)

<generator object Response.iter_content.<locals>.generate at 0x7ffa2dsa7820>
            
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open('output_image_{}.png'.format(c), 'w') as data:
    for chunk in img_obj:
       s3.upload_fileobj(data,'mybucket','img/{}'.format(chunk))
```

Error:

```
Input <_io.BufferedWriter name='output_image_1.png'> of type: <class '_io.BufferedWriter'> is not supported.
```

On local machine, I am able to write the file:

```
with open("output_image_{}.png".format(c), "w") as fp:
    for chunk in img_obj:
       fp.write(chunk)
```

I'd like to directly save the `img_obj` on AWS S3.

Comment: @jarmod any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the `s3fs` to save the image in `png` format.

I could recreate and achieve the sample using the below code:

```
from PIL import Image
import s3fs

s3=s3fs.S3FileSystem(client_kwargs=<aws_credentials>)


img_obj = Image.open('sample_file.png')
img_obj.save(s3.open('s3:///<bucket_name>/sample_file.png', 'wb'), 'PNG')
```

[image]